# Naming conventions with objects vs collections (PHP)

Tags: naming-conventions, collaboration, convention

When I have a class `Car` that represents a single car, and a class `Cars` that implements methods which manipulate `Car` objects and one of whose methods will return a `Collection` of `Car` objects, how would I "have to" name my variable that holds the instantiated `Cars` object?

For example:

```
$whatDoINameThis = new Cars;
$cars = $whatDoINameThis->getAllCars();
```

Since it is an instantiation of the `Cars` object, the intuitive name for it would be `$cars`, but the second variable in my code is the one that actually holds cars, so it's more intuitive if I name that one `$cars`.

Is there some nice and tidy, popular and agreed-upon convention as to what I should name my first variable in such cases?

Please don't mark the question as "opinion-based". I'm asking about conventions, or what is good for collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

The name I use for the inner collection of a collection-like class that holds its elements is `contents`.